# Ember template - pass parameters from child to parent in function call

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember component that gets created in a loop. I pass a function down with a parameter. The child will need to pass another parameter for the function to work. How do I achieve this?

Ex:

```
Parent:
<div>
  {{#each items as |item index|}}
    <Child 
      @onButton1Click={{fn this.doStuff index}} // need index to do stuff
    />
  {{/each}}
</div>

Child:
<div>
  <ColorSelector @onColorChange={{this.changeColor}}/>
  <Button @onClick={{this.onButton1ClickAction}} />
</div>
```

```js
// Parent.js

@action
doStuff(index, color) {
  // calculate stuff using color and index
}
```

```js
// Child.js

@tracked
color = 'blue';

@action 
changeColor(passedColor) {
  this.color = passedColor; // some hex value
}

@action
onButton1ClickAction() {
  this.args.onButton1Click?.(this.color);
  // how do I pass back color
}
```

Question is, how can I use pass color from the child and maintain index from the parent? Currently only index is seen.

Comment: your code should work exactly as it is. what is not working?

Comment: no, the color parameter is ignored

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
  <Child 
      onButton1Click={{fn this.doStuff index}} // need index to do stuff
    />
```

should be

```
  <Child 
      @onButton1Click={{fn this.doStuff index}} // need index to do stuff
    />
```

and

```
  <ColorSelector onColorChange={{this.changeColor}}/>
  <Button onClick={{this.onButton1ClickAction}} />
```

should be

```
  <ColorSelector @onColorChange={{this.changeColor}}/>
  <Button @onClick={{this.onButton1ClickAction}} />
```

(note the `@`)

without the `@`, `onButton1Click` is interpreted as an html-attribute, which would be applied to the element in `Child` with `...attributes` (if it exists), otherwise `onButton1Click` wouldn't do anything.

relevant docs: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-arguments-and-html-attributes/

Comment: sorry, my canned example didn't include the @ but my real code has it

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had to execute parent function from the child

```
//child.js
@tracked
color = 'blue';

@action 
changeColor(passedColor) {
  this.color = passedColor; // some hex value
}

@action
onButton1ClickAction() {
  const click = this.args.onButton1Click ?? null;
  if (click) {
     click(this.color)
}
```